# How to check whether user is inputting alphanumeric or not during registration process

Tags: php

I am trying to make a login system and i got stuck when checking whether user has entered alphanumeric or not.

I checked out many tutorials which say **ctype alnum** can be used to do so. But i was unable to do that.
My code and question is below

```
$rusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['rusername']);
$rpassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['rpassword']); 
$crpassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['crpassword']);
if ($rpassword != $crpassword) {
    echo "The password's doesn't match";
}
```

i don't know how to create a code which checks whether alphanumeric has been inputted into required fields and if so they should get notification as we see in many popular sites.

Thanks

Comment: If you are going to apply this to a users password. Don't. User's passwords should be allowed to be anything a user wishes to input. Since you will be using `password_hash` to store it, there is no sql injection worries (which you should also be using prepared statements anyhow in that regard too).

Comment: whey then popular companies do

Comment: @karen all validation must be server side, as no user input can be trusted. One can still add client side validation, but it shall not be wholly relied upon.

Comment: @RaashidDinDar No idea what "popular companies" you are referring too that has abysmal password restrictions that prohibit actually secure passwords to be entered. Maybe you should look to "proper companies" instead.

Comment: @IncredibleHat i am not trying to say that. You know Godady when a user registers if he doesn't use alphanumeric passwords he can't register that is what i want

Comment: Well, they have imposed that for their own reasons. A better-practice for passwords is to allow all ascii characters (not just a-Z 0-9). Some more modern sites allow a full utf8 charset to be used for passwords. The main point here is, you are creating a hash of the password to store and verify against. A password of `©72*_±:lWijf^™hFe&^Tbh2ƒ` is perfectly acceptable when using `password_hash() / password_verify()` like you should be using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were already right about using [`ctype_alnum`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alnum.php) but not sure why it didn't work for you.

The other comments made a good point about either validating at the form level or dealing with a hashed password but just to answer your question anyways here's how it might look:

```
$rusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['rusername']);
$rpassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['rpassword']); 
$crpassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['crpassword']);

if ($rpassword != $crpassword) {
    echo "The password's doesn't match";
} elseif (!ctype_alnum($rpassword)) {
    echo "Please use alphanumeric password!";
}
```

Comment: can you please edit my code because that way i will grab it more. Hope you don't mind